# WSDL missing data type definitions

Tags: java, netbeans, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I am building a SOAP web service with JAX WS. One of the clients should be SAP. After developing my service ports directly in Java with NetBeans I tried to connect to the service using the WSDL XML file.

My problem is, that it is well defined but its missing datatype definitions. Is there a way to get the missing parts for the WSDL with NetBeans?

For example, one of my ports returns a complex data type which is a Java object called ReportResponse. It contains 2 Strings, a Boolean and an Integer field. The WSDL for this parts looks like this:

```
  <message name="reportResponse">
  <part name="parameters" element="tns:reportResponse" /> 
  </message>
```

The problem is that "tns:reportResponse" is not further defined in my WSDL file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer the .xsd file for your wsdl. There should be complex type definition to element"reportResponse". You can find the xsd .

If you load the wsdl to netbeans by url the case is jaxws  can not find your xsd file. Best way is to download wsdl and xsd to your local folder and load them to netbeans.

Comment: Where can I find the XSD? I can get the WSDL via HTTP get... Where is it located?

Comment: In your wsdl file there will be following tag <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="..." schemaLocation="XSD Location"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types> .

Comment: Sorry... I was a bit messy today... Just didn't see the import declaration!

Comment: post Your  wsdl .I will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Is it defined independently on a XSD? If so, you should use an import statement referencing your XSD URL...